# How does the product $q_j X^j_m$ make sense in this context?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, proof-explanation

I am reading **Section:** Polynomials in Several Indeterminates from textbook **Analysis I** by *Herbert Amann* and *Joachim Escher*.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Previously, the authors define $X^\alpha_\beta$ as follows

> [image]

---

In Remark (c), I could not understand why $p = \sum_\alpha p_\alpha X^\alpha$ can be written in the form $p = \sum_{j=0}^n q_j X^j_m$ for suitable $n \in \Bbb N$ and $q_j \in K[X_1,\cdots,X_{m-1}]$.

In my understanding, $X^j_m = \begin{cases}1, &j=m \\ 0, &j\neq m \end{cases}$. As a result, $X^j_m \in K$.

> I could not understand how the product $q_j X^j_m$ makes sense.

Please shed me some light. Thank you so much!

---

**Update:** I have added screenshots of this entire section so that you can grasp authors' ideas more easily.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the notation. Even if you are, the product still would make sense

Comment: Hi @MattSamuel, please elaborate more on the meaning of the product $q_j X^j_m$! I really do not understand that point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $X_i$ are indeterminates and do not have specific values. In the proof, the approach is to factor out the highest power of $X_m$ in each term so that you have a polynomial in one variable, namely $X_m$, except that the coefficients are in $K[X_1,\ldots,X_{m-1}]$. We are identifying $K[X_1,\ldots,X_{m-1}][X_m] $ with $K[X_1,\ldots,X_{m} ]$.

Comment: Hi Matt, does the term $X^j_m$ mean $X^j_m = \begin{cases}1, &j=m \\ 0, &j\neq m \end{cases}$ as I observed?

Comment: @LeAnh No, it's a variable raised to a power. Imagine the $m$ isn't there (it's just an index), so we'd have $X^j$, or $x^j$ if you like that better. But the $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ are different variables, and you are raising them to powers.

Comment: It is hard for me to understand since the authors do not define such $X_1,\ldots,X_m$. I have added screenshots of this entire section on **Polynomials in Several Indeterminates**. I hope that you can have a look at them and elaborate on my issue.

Comment: @LeAnh There's nothing to define. They're just symbols you can add and multiply.

Comment: @Le I see how the notation could be confusing. It's a vector as the index there.